# Infinitive ' habere ' usage in this sentence

Tags: grammar-choice, new-latin, grammar-identification, spinoza, infinitive

How to understand a meaning of the infinitive 'habere' here, is it here as a subject (The Infinitive as a Subject, Gildersleeve & Lodge, page 275)?

> Nam cum posse existere potentia sit, sequitur quo plus realitatis alicujus rei naturæ competit *eo plus virium a se* **habere** *ut existat* adeoque Ens absolute infinitum sive Deum infinitam absolute potentiam existendi a se habere, qui propterea absolute existit.  (Spinoza, Ethics)<

For, as the potentiality of existence is a power, it follows that, in proportion as reality increases in the nature of a thing, so also will it increase its strength for existence. Therefore a being absolutely infinite, such as God, has from himself an absolutely infinite power of existence, and hence he does absolutely exist. (R.H.M.Elwes)

> eo plus virium a se **habere** ut existat <

..., more strength from itself (it would) possess in order to exist,...

Comment: Good question! This truly puzzled me when I answered the [earlier question on the same phrase](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2204/79).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Accusativum cum infinitivo* triggered by *sequitur*, though the accusative has been ellipsed: 'it follows that it has...'

This use falls under definition 7 of *sequor* in the *Oxford Latin Dictionary*:

> 7 To follow from (a premiss), follow logically.

Attestations:

> (*w. acc. and inf.*) nec si omne enuntiatum aut uerum aut falsum est, ~quitur ilico esse causas immutabilis .. quae .. Cic. *Fat.* 28; Lucr. 3.665.

Comment: But how does 'competit',then fits in, why not 'competere' in it's place? @cnread

Comment: @aili-j It's not infinitive because quo...competit is a subordinate clause within the ACI construction, triggered by eo. Main idea: 'it follows that it has from itself more strength for existing to that degree'; subordinate ([cor]relative) clause: '(to the degree) that more reality belongs to the nature of some thing.'